# Add to openFrameworks project external libraries?

Tags: c++, xcode, class, sensors, openframeworks

I'm building a cross-platform mobile application and I was suggested to use OF environment and compile my application using Xcode. I'm a Mac user and I started programming few time ago (so I'm really a beginner).

I need some class to get information about position and rotation so I was thinking to have a look at some SDK such as MoSync or CMDeviceMotion in order to understand which one is the most suitable to my purpose.
I also noted here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMDeviceMotion

that CMDeviceMotion is written for Obj-C and Swift.

So I have two question:

1. is it possible add to the main project libraries that are not part of OF?
2. should I use only C/C++ class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if stackoverflow is the right place to ask a q like this, since any answer is very much prone to subjectivity.

I don't think there's a lot of valid reasons to even try to connect "MoSync" with OF, since they are both in a way "platforms" for developing apps, supporting different languages (javascript on the first and c++ on the latter). It is possible to mix objective-c (and swift) code with c++, so you can combine CMDeviceMotion with OF.

However to answer your question: It seems that if you want to have device information you don't need to go out of the scope of openFrameworks. Take a look at the ["ofxIOSCoreLocation"](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/ofxiOS/ofxiOSCoreLocation.html)class of OpenFrameworks/ofxIOS. It provides means for altitude, location, direction and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible to cross Objective-C and C++ with what is called Objective-C++ (by standard .mm instead of cpp), in openFrameworks.

Limitations and features: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B

You can then from the Objective-C++ class (lets say for example ofApp.h), call Objective C delegates and functions directly.

You can not embed swift like this, however you there are some methods of using objective-c middle man class.